# Recipe Finder, Python 3. Definition error when saving a recipe

Tags: python

Below is the code that I have the issue with. When it comes to saving a new recipe, it comes up with an error saying that 'dish' is not defined. 'dish' is the variable that holds the recipe name. To get to this stage, the name must have already been entered, and so I fail to see why the error should occur. I would be very grateful to here of any comments and tips, as i have hit the metaphorical 'brick wall.'

import sys

```
recipes = []
ingredients = []
quantities = []

menu = "What would you like to do? \n 1) Make a recipe \n 2) Load a recipe \n 3) Exit \n\
"

def save_recipe(recipe, file_name):
    file = open(file_name, "w")
    file.write(recipe)
    file.close()

def decision_functions():
    interface_choice = input(menu)
    if (interface_choice == "1" or "Make a recipe"):
        dish = input("What do you wish to make?: ")
        ingredients_loop()
    elif (interface_choice == "2" or "Load a recipe"):
        decision = input("What recipe do you wish to load?: ")
        decision += ".txt"
        file = open(decision, "r")
        recipe = (file.read())
        serves = int(input("How many do you wish to serve?: "))
        recipe = list(recipe)


    elif (interface_choice == "3" or "Exit"):
        print("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit

    else:
        print("I don't understand. . . Please select one of the above numbered options. \n\
")
        decision_functions

def ingredients_loop():
    ingredient = input("Name an ingredient in the recipe. Type END when done: ")
    if (ingredient == "end"):
        def confirm_decision():
            print(ingredients)
            print(quantities)
            confirmation = input("Is this all?: ")
            if (confirmation == "yes"):
                recipe = [ingredients, "\n\
"                       , quantities]
                file_name = dish.replace(' ', '') + ".txt"
                writerecipe(str(recipe), file_name)
                print("Your recipe has been saved")
                decision_functions()
            elif (confirmation == "no"):
                print("Preparing to allow more ingredients. . .")
                ingredients_loop()
            else:
                print("I do not understand . . .")
                confirm_decision()
        confirm_decision() 
    else:
        ingredient += ":"
        ingredients.append (ingredient)
        amount = int(input("How much of this ingredeint is required to serve one?: "))
        units = (input("What unit is this measurement in?: "))
        amts = amount, units
        quantities.append (amts)
    ingredients_loop()


decision_functions()
```

Comment: Dish is a local variable to decision_functions. It's out of scope for ingredients_loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using dish inside the `ingredients_loop`  Which is not accessible since you have declared inside the `decision_functions`

What you can do is either make dish as global or pass the dish to `ingredients_loop`

```
recipes = []
ingredients = []
quantities = []
dish =""

menu = "What would you like to do? \n 1) Make a recipe \n 2) Load a recipe \n 3) Exit \n\
"
```

specify `dish`  as global

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Had a few errors after this, but got it working soon after. Thanks again for your help.